# 'who' doesn't always print hostnames

Tags: debian, login

I'm having a hard time parsing this output from who on my debian sid:

```
user1   pts/1        2016-12-31 00:32 (:pts/2:S.0)
user2   pts/3        2016-12-31 10:19 (c-76-103-173-249.hsd1.ca.comcast.net)
user2   pts/5        2016-12-31 10:19 (tmux(17104).%1)
user3   pts/14       2017-01-01 14:48 (c-73-11-0-160:S.0)
```

I get the `:pts` and `tmux` entries, and the full comcast fqdn. But what does the `:S.0` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (S:0) means it runs in screen in widows 0

Comment: And if that user has no other entry in who? (even though they're currently logged in)?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Could you show some example where "user has no other entry in who". Besides of `screen` and `tmux` there is one more mechanism to leave process running and log out, it is `nohup` utility which doesn't use terminal's file descriptors that is why it survives on log out.

Comment: `who` has one line for this user, as listed above. `w` shows the same, adding that the process running is irssi.

Grepping `ps -ef`, I see `SCREEN -U` and `/bin/bash`, both launched days earlier (so probably from a connection that is no longer there).

Comment: Yes, `screen`, `tmux` and `nohup` is a way to run some program as a service since they doesn't glue file descriptors (STDIN, STDOUT,STDERR) of particular connection to running processes that is exactly why programs running under these three guys  can survive actual disconnect and can still run and show up in `w`